# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(f(x)) =f(x)$ then which one is correct

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As stated in the title;  Let  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function satisfying $f(f(x))$ = $f(x)$   then

(a) $f$ must be constant

(b) $f(x) = x$ for all  $x$ in range of $f$

(c) $f$ must be a non constant polynomial

(d) There is no such function

By randomly trying different functions I discovered that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = 1-x$ satisfy given property . So using this option (c) seems to be correct.

But , My question is that  How can I make sure that these are the only functions that hold this property  ? and if there are any other function (other than these two)  then  how should I find them .

Thank you

Comment: Note:  the header question says $f(f(x))=x$, but in the body of the post you say $f(f(x))=f(x)$.  Which did you intend?

Comment: @lulu sorry,it was a typo i have edited the question now.

Comment: Are you sure?  Given $f(x)=1-x$ we have $f\circ f(x)=f(1-x)=1-(1-x)=x\neq f(x)$.

Comment: constant functions also meet the condition

Comment: $|x|$ satisfies the given conditions and isn't a polynomial.

Comment: If $f$ is onto I think the only option is identity .

Comment: @lulu thanks for the example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be $b$. Suppose not. That means there exists $f$ and there exists $y_0$ such that we have some $x_0$ with $f(x_0)=y_0$ and we have $f(y_0)\neq y_0$.

Then, $f(x_0)=y_0$, but $f(f(x_0))=f(y_0)\neq y_0$, which contradicts the assumtion that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: What you're arguing for, it's (b), not (c).

Comment: Ah thanks, excuse the mistake.

Comment: @EBP but what about $f(x) = \mid x\mid $?

Comment: This statement holds for $f(x)=|x|$. The image of $f(x)$ is $[0,\infty)$, and this is exactly the domain where $f(x)$ itself is the identity.

Comment: thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is in the range of $f$ means $x=f(y)$ for some $y$. Since $f(f(y))=f(y)$ you have $f(x)=x$.

Just to see how arbitrary your function may be I give the following example satisfying your conditions:

$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
x,&|x|\leq 1\\
\sin(\pi x/2),& |x|>1
\end{array}\right.
$$